# integral of $x^{-\frac{1}{x}}\cos x$ from $1$ to $\infty$ does not converge:

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, improper-integrals

It seems clear to me that the integral:
$$\int_1^{+\infty}x^{-\frac{1}{x}}\cos xdx$$
can not converge, but I'm not sure how to actually prove it. I thought to use confront criteria but $\int_1^{+\infty}x^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ diverges, hence it's not helpful. What is the idea to use here?

Comment: Certainly $x^{-1/x} \cos x \not \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$...

Comment: Indeed $x^{-\frac{1}{x}}\cos x$ goes to $1$ as $x\rightarrow+\infty$, so yeah the integrand function is not infinitesimal.

Comment: Well, ..., no.  $x^{-1/x} \rightarrow 1$, so the integrand $\rightarrow \cos x$.  But you should know that $\lim_{u \rightarrow \infty} \int_1^u \cos x \,\mathrm{d}x$ doesn't exist (because, for example, $\cos x \not\rightarrow 0$).

Comment: It is true that it doesn't converge to $0$, but there are integrals such that $f(x)$ does not converge to $0$ at infinity and yet $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ converges.

Comment: I'm sorry but $|x^{-\frac{1}{x}}\cos x|\leq x^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ holds true and $x^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ goes to 1

Comment: @DavideTrono This only shows that your integral (in absolute value) is smaller than a divergent integral. This doesn't mean it itself is divergent.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I was answering to @EricTowers last comment.

Comment: The limit behaviour in your new comment is correct.  The limit behaviour in your prior comment is not.  Are you able to show $\int^\infty \cos$ does not converge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By integration by parts, one has
$$\int_1^{+\infty}x^{-\frac{1}{x}}\cos xdx=x^{-\frac{1}{x}}\sin x\bigg|_1^{+\infty}-\int_1^{+\infty}x^{-\frac{1}{x}}\bigg(-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{\ln x}{x^2}\bigg)\sin xdx.$$
Noting that the integral above converges and the first term diverges, one can conclude that the original integral diverges.